# JSON parser doesn't work with Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to access json obj and set values into Angular Ui-grid.But the problem was that some of my json obj fields are json string.I tried to convert that fields into json obt using Json.parser and then try to access.But nothing can display and wont give any error message.

*Json Obj*

```
[  
   {  
      "jobId":"efe0ace0-8ed9-45ff-9232-974cbdc89b86",
      "jobType":"TestJob",
      "nextRun":"N/A",
      "lastRun":"2015-11-26 13:26:10.664",
      "createdDate":"2015-11-26 13:26:10.664",
      "executor":"g",
      "JobDetails":"{\"environment\":\"TQ\",\"additionalEmailRecipients\":[\"g.g@gmail.com\"],\"extraParams\":{\"PlanFileName\":\"RestAPI.xml\"}}",
      "status":"active",
      "elapsedTime":"1 day ago"
   }
]
```

I tried to convert `JobDetails` field into json obj inside cell template.

```
var testPlantemplate ='<div><ul><li ng-repeat="testPlans in JSON.parse(row.entity.JobDetails)">{{testPlans.environment}}</li></ul></div>';
```

*Complete Js Script*

```
'use strict';
var tepTableModule = angular.module('test',
        [ 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch','ui.grid','ngResource' ]).factory('Service',
        function($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/job/jobs', {});
        });

    tepTableModule
    .controller(
            'tepTableCtrl',
            function($scope, Service) {
                $scope.TestData = Service.query();

        //This doesn't work     
               var testPlantemplate ='<div><ul><li ng-repeat="testPlans in JSON.parse(row.entity.JobDetails)">{{testPlans.environment}}</li></ul></div>';

                $scope.tableData = {
                    data : 'TestData',

                    groupsCollapsedByDefault : true,


                    enablePinning : true,
                    columnDefs : [ {
                        field : 'jobId',
                        displayName : 'jobId',
                        visible : false
                    },  {
                        field : 'JobDetails',
                        displayName : 'Test Plan Name',
                        cellTemplate : testPlantemplate,
                        visible : true
                    },
                     {
                        field : 'jobType',
                        displayName : 'JobType',
                        visible : true
                    },
                     {
                        field : 'environment',
                        displayName : 'Environments',
                        visible : true
                    },
                     {
                        field : 'status',
                        displayName : 'Status',
                        visible : true
                    },
                    {
                        field : 'elapsedTime',
                        displayName : 'LastRun',
                        visible : true
                    },
                    {
                        field : 'JobDetails.additionalEmailRecipients',
                        displayName : 'Email Recipients',
                        visible : true
                    },
                    {
                        field : 'executor',
                        displayName : 'Executor',
                        visible : true
                    }
                    ],
                    sortInfo: {
                          fields: ['elapsedTime'],
                          directions: ['desc']
                        },
                    plugins : [ new ngGridAutoRowHeightPlugin() ]
                };

                $scope.changeGroupBy = function(group) {
                    $scope.gridOptions.groupBy(group);
                }
                $scope.clearGroupBy = function() {
                    $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.configGroups = [];
                    $scope.gridOptions.groupBy();
                }

            });
```

Please let me know how can i access `JobDetails` inside ng-repeat and set into ui-grid.

Answer (score 2):

Create a method in scope

```
$scope.parseJSON=function(strObj){
  return JSON.parse(strObj);
}
```

Then call from template

```
var testPlantemplate ='<div><ul><li ng-repeat="testPlans in parseJSON(row.entity.JobDetails)">{{testPlans.environment}}</li></ul></div>';
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p1mnh7x9/)**</kbd>

Comment: I tried but function doesn't execute.I put `console.log` inside function.

Comment: can you produce it in jsfiddle with dummy data ? @gihan

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle and tried to access  but doesn't execute when accesing jobDetails. http://jsfiddle.net/p1mnh7x9/2/

Comment: i was able to acces `jobdetails` but problem is that when comes to ui-grid it wont work.http://jsfiddle.net/p1mnh7x9/3/  instead of `current` to ` row.entity.JobDetails`

Comment: @gihan sorry to say i have no idea about ui-grid. you can ask separately

Answer (score 1):

can you try with stringify() then it escapes all of "/"...

```
    var testPlantemplate ='<div><ul><li ng-repeat="testPlans in JSON.stringify(row.entity.JobDetails)">{{testPlans.environment}}</li></ul></div>';
```

check this link...

http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch22.html