# Json parser doesnt work with AngularJs Ui-Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to generate Angular [Ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) using complex json object.I used cell-template to display custom columns.

```
var testPlantemplate ='<div><ul><li ng-repeat="testPlans in JSON.parse(row.entity.JobDetails)">{{testPlans.environment}}</li></ul></div>';
```

Seems like problem was in `ng-repeat`.i can not convert json string into json obj using Json.parser in `row.entity` attribute like in above code snippet.Please let me know that how can i convert row.entity as a Json object.My requirement is that i want to access `JobDetails` Json element and set into custom template.

More details in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992413/json-parser-doesnt-work-with-angular-ng-repeat).

*Json Obj*

```
[  
   {  
      "jobId":"efe0ace0-8ed9-45ff-9232-974cbdc89b86",
      "jobType":"TestJob",
      "nextRun":"N/A",
      "lastRun":"2015-11-26 13:26:10.664",
      "createdDate":"2015-11-26 13:26:10.664",
      "executor":"g",
      "JobDetails":"{\"environment\":\"TQ\",\"additionalEmailRecipients\":[\"g.g@gmail.com\"],\"extraParams\":{\"PlanFileName\":\"RestAPI.xml\"}}",
      "status":"active",
      "elapsedTime":"1 day ago"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use external function inside a directive like in your example, then you should assign that function to the **$scope**

Example:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope){

    $scope.JSON = JSON;

});
```

Then the JSON object should be available in the directive.

Comment: I already did that.http://jsfiddle.net/58f36s5d/1/ here is the jsfiddle link.Please refer my other question for more details.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avo4gxzo/1/ There were a couple of things that were not correct like badly formatted JSON string.

Comment: @ Synapse i think this is the wrong jsfiddle.this shows me a simple angularjs code.my requirement is that angular with ui grid.any way thanks.

Comment: Sorry copied the wrong fiddle address and lost the working one. Made a new one: http://jsfiddle.net/yL5qdg2L/7/

Comment: do you have any idea how to set values from json into environment column in grid. `JobDetails.environment` . this code snippet doesnt run for me. `<li ng-repeat="testPlans in JSON.parse(row.entity.JobDetails)">{{testPlans.environment}}</li>` .

Comment: If the JSON parser does not fire then maybe you're not under the right $scope, but without seeing the code it is difficult to find what's wrong. As you can see from the fiddle the example works

Comment: @ Synapse here is the sample code snippet http://jsfiddle.net/58f36s5d/1/
yes in your example is working fine but i have a complex json object to access. if you know anything about this please let me know.

Comment: I fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58f36s5d/10/ As I was saying before the JSON string was badly formated. Remove the Factory because was incomplete and removed the ui-grid plugin because was missing from the dependecies.